# Unable to connect to database from C

Tags: sql, c, postgresql

I wrote a function to connect to a SQL database

```
void Test(){                        

    PGconn *conn;
    PGresult *res;
    conn = PQconnectdb("dbname=metocean host=try user=Test password=test");

    fprintf(stderr, "Connection to database failed: %s", PQerrorMessage(conn));
}
```

I call it in a for loop and it works fine for some cycles but after a while I get the error

```
Connection to database failed: could not create socket: Too many open files
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Print the exact error message,
        fprintf(stderr, "Connection to database failed: %s",
                PQerrorMessage(conn));

Comment: @NaveenKumar see edited post. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it closing the connection.

I added the lines

```
    res = PQexec(conn, "CLOSE myportal");
    PQclear(res);
    PQfinish(conn);
```

and it worked.